# Colorbox - I'm looking into adding a url at the bottom of displayed image. This link will pass the image location to this frame src

Tags: javascript, php, url, colorbox, src

Colorbox - I'm looking into adding a url at the bottom of displayed image.  This link will pass the image location to this frame src for example:

```
--frame src="annotate.php?folder=2013&image=20130506_000043_2048_0193.jpg" name="frame1" --
```

The image location will be passed into **annotate.php** which is an annotation script to record mouse click coordinates. I can hard code an image for testing, but have yet to find a slick way to push an image from a gallery to the annotate.php module. We integrated a colorbox gallery into the web app and would hope to use the galler to send the image.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edits Skatox

Comment: Perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this without meddling down in the weeds with a colorbox gallery addon. I really don't know how typically a querystring is built in this case ( I don't have much experience with building querystring but do understand the purpose). We just want to see the image and somehow put the image name into the frame src as above. thanks!